# How do i check the big O for complexity function

Tags: big-o

I have this:

```
a) f(n) = n
b) f(n) = 1045n
c) f(n) = n2 + 70
d) f(n) = 7n + 3
e) f(n) = Cn + D (where C and D are both constants)
f) f(n) = 8
g) f(n) = n3 + n + 1
h) f(n) = 4n + 2log n + 5
```

I want to check if the Big O notation of them is O(n).

How can I determinate it?

And how to find the Big-O notation for the functions below:

```
a) f(n) = 3n3 + n
b) f(n) = 3 log n + 5n
c) f(n) = 3n2 + 5n + 4
d) f(n) = 3n3 + n2 + 5n + 99
```

Comment: Do you mean `o(n)` or `O(n)`. There is a big difference.

Comment: Well it's the big O notation, i don't know the difference between the two, can you explain? I believe in this case what i need is the O(n)

Comment: In general you write `f(n) = O(g(n))` if `f(n) <= C * g(n)` for some constant `C` for large enough `n`. It's like `<=`, so for any `f` you always have `f(n) = O(f(n))`. You write `f(n) = o(g(n))` if `f(n) < C * g(n))` for EVERY C for large enough `n`. So `f` is somehow strictly less than `g`. It's never true that `f (n) = o(f(n))`.

Comment: Although the formalism might require a bit of thought to really digest, the example on wikipedia is really easy to follow. Please have a look at it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example

Comment: this might also be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f(x) is O(g(x)) if there exists a constant c such that f(x) < c*g(x)
```

You should look at the "biggest" asymptoticall factor in your function (highest exponent or something like that) and that would be your big O

Example: `f(n) = 2^n + n^5 + n^2 + n*log(n) + n`

 This function has 5 different factors that influence big O, sorted from biggest to smallest, so this one would be O(2^n). Drop the `2^n` and now `f(n)` is `O(n^5)`.

Constants are O(1).

Hope I explained it well

Answer (score 1):

Generally the Big O notation of a function is measured by the largest power of n that appears. In your case, this would be n², since the only other factor is the 70 which is constant.

Edit: Original post only contained the function f(n) = n² + 70.

Comment: yeah i had to add the rest, i'm studying for a test and I don't know how to do the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4852666/1669475).

In short, there's no set way to determine Big O results. Strictly speaking any function which eventually (for some `n`) will always be bigger than your function, is Big O of it. In practice you're looking for as tight a bound as you can get. If the only components of the function are polynomial in `n`, then the Big O will just be the largest power of `n` that appears (or rather, `n` to that power). Another useful thing to know is that `log n` is of a lower order than `n` (but higher than constant).